# ListView in Flyout transition issue

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using a grouped `ListView` inside a `Flyout` and get weird UI issue with group header when popup opens. It happens for a fraction of second, but still notable by most of the users.

[image: header animation bug]

XAML (excerpt from full repro sample http://ge.tt/1DWlXbq1/v/0?c):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupHeaderTemplate">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Key}"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                        Margin="0 20" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsViewSource"
                          IsSourceGrouped="True"
                          Source="{Binding Items}" />
</Page.Resources>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Caption">
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}"
                              Margin="20 0">
                        <ListView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}" />
                        </ListView.GroupStyle>
                    </ListView>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

I cannot use built-in `ListPickerFlyout` as it doesn't support grouping.

I tried to find corresponding storyboard or transition in default styles for `ListView`/`Flyout`, but wasn't able to.

I'd like to fix that animation or disable it at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You say you did look through all the animations or you just couldn't find the one for that particular thing?

Comment: @ChrisW. I couldn't find the one for that particular thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get rid of the weird animation bug is to let the `Flyout` control's animation run first, and then after the animation finishes, show the `ListView`.

To do this, you need to subscribe to the following events in the `Flyout` control. Also you need to give the `ListView` a name and set its `Opacity` to `0` to start with.

```
   <Flyout Opened="Flyout_Opened" Closed="Flyout_Closed">
       <ListView x:Name="MyListView" Opacity="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}" Margin="20 0">
```

Then in the code behind, you show the `ListView` after a short delay. I created a little `Opacity` animation for the `ListView` just to make the whole transition run more smoothly. Each time the `Flyout` is closed, we reset the `ListView` back to invisible.

```
private async void Flyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    // a short delay to allow the Flyout in animation to take place
    await Task.Delay(400);

    // animate in the ListView
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200),
        To = 1
    };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this.MyListView);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Opacity");

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}

private void Flyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
{
    this.MyListView.Opacity = 0;
}
```

However, having provided a possible solution, I don't think using a `Flyout` control to change the visual style is the right approach here.

The `Flyout` control is not designed to handle large amount of data. It doesn't support virtualization (I think). For example, if you increase the item count from 30 to 300, it's going to take quite a few seconds to load once you hit the button.

**Update (Working sample included)**

I was thinking maybe I could create a control that handles all this, 'cause at the end of the day you do want to be able to retrieve the item that you clicked in the list as well as close the popup.

Unfortunately `ListPickerFlyout` is sealed so I chose to create a control that inherits from `Flyout`.

It's quite straight forward. Basically the control exposes properties like `ItemsSource`, `SelectedItem`, etc. Also it subscribes to the `ItemClick` event of the `ListView` so whenever an item is clicked, it closes the `Flyout` and populate the `SelectedItem`.

```
public class ListViewFlyout : Flyout
{
    private ListView _listView;

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(ListViewFlyout), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public DataTemplate HeaderTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(HeaderTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ListViewFlyout), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ListViewFlyout), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(ListViewFlyout), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ListViewFlyout()
    {
        // initialization
        this.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Full;
        _listView = new ListView
        {
            Opacity = 0,
            IsItemClickEnabled = true
        };

        this.Opened += ListViewFlyout_Opened;
        this.Closed += ListViewFlyout_Closed;
    }

    private async void ListViewFlyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(400);

        if (!_listView.Items.Any())
        {
            // assign the listView as the Content of this 'custom control'
            _listView.ItemsSource = this.ItemsSource;
            _listView.ItemTemplate = this.ItemTemplate;
            _listView.GroupStyle.Add(new GroupStyle { HeaderTemplate = this.HeaderTemplate });
            this.Content = _listView;

            // whenever an item is clicked, we close the Layout and assign the SelectedItem
            _listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;
        }

        // animate in the list
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200),
            To = 1
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, _listView);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Opacity");
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }

    private void ListViewFlyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
    {
        _listView.Opacity = 0;
    }

    private async void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedItem = e.ClickedItem;
        this.Hide();

        // to be removed
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(e.ClickedItem.ToString() + " was clicked 1 sec ago!");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

The xaml becomes as simple as this.

```
    <AppBarButton Icon="Caption">
        <AppBarButton.Flyout>
            <local:ListViewFlyout ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}" FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutPresenterStyle}" />
        </AppBarButton.Flyout>
    </AppBarButton>
```

Note in the `FlyoutPresenterStyle` style I have created a `Title` for the popup too.

I have also included a fully functional sample [here](http://1drv.ms/1sXkNSJ).

Comment: I know how to change the look of the items and looking for a ways to display a picker with grouping capabilities. The only problem here is that standard `ListPickerFlyout` doesn't support that.

Comment: thank you. I got the idea. However, animation bug is still there when I open flyout for the first time on emulator. I believe timings should be adjusted further.

Comment: Hey @altso, did you test this on a real device or, run emulator without debugger? Because when debugger is attached, there's serious performance hit when running an app. I have tested this on 520, 920 and 1020, all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I found a workaround.
I find performances are pretty poor, even without the workaround. It takes about 1s to load completely on my device (Lumia 920).

I believe the responsible is the `ItemsStackPanel`, which is the default `ItemsPanel` for the `ListView`. When I use another panel the issue does not occurs. However the scrollviewer offset does not reset when I close and reopen the flyout, therefore I have to do it manually.

So I used a `VirtalizingStackPanel` in order to keep the virtualization.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

And when the ListView loads, we find the ListView ScrollViewer, and scroll to the top.

```
private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = (ListView)sender;            
        var scrollviewer = listView.FindFirstChild<ScrollViewer>();
        scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
    }
```

`listView.FindFirstChild<ScrollViewer>();` is just a helper I have to find child controls with `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild`.

I find this solution a little better in terms of performance :
I set the ListView Visibility to Collapsed by default :

```
<ListView Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

I subscribe to the Flyout `Opened` and `Closed` events :

```
<Flyout Placement="Full"
        Opened="Flyout_Opened"
        Closed="Flyout_Closed" />
```

Then, when the flyout open, I change the visibility after 400ms.

```
private async void Flyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(400);
        var listView = (ListView)((Flyout)sender).Content;
        listView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Flyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
    {
        var listView = (ListView)((Flyout)sender).Content;
        listView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Also, by default, the flyout has a `ScrollViewer`, which will break the virtualization.
You need to remove it from the `FlyoutPresenter` control Template, or disable it with `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode`.

Comment: It seems that setting `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` of `FlyoutPresenter` is enough to enable virtualization. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, weird animation comes from `ItemsStackPanel`. Therefore, if (and only if) virtualization is not required, it's possible to specify `StackPanel` as `ItemsPanel`:

```
<Flyout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}"
              Margin="20 0">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}" />
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Flyout>
```

Comment: One more thing to note is that you will lose the sticky header too. :)